# How to validate windows domain credentials via the command line?

Tags: windows, user-accounts, windows-domain

I want to validate a set of credentials against the domain controller. e.g.:

```
Username: STACKOVERFLOW\joel
Password: splotchy
```

Can I do this via the command line?

Comment: Is the computer you are doing the testing on already a member of the domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a very handy PowerShell function [here](http://poshcode.org/1393) for testing credentials:

```
Function Test-ADCredentials {
     Param($username, $password, $domain)
     Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
     $ct = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Domain
     $pc = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext($ct, $domain)
     New-Object PSObject -Property @{
          UserName = $username;
          IsValid = $pc.ValidateCredentials($username, $password).ToString()
     }
}
```

Example use: `Test-ADCrendentials -Username joel -Password splotchy -Domain stackoverflow.com`

Answer (score 0):

I tend to just connect to a share on the server:

net use \server\share * /user:domain\username

You're then prompted for a password and if the correct one is entered you now have a connection to the server and a response that the command completed successfully.